# Google Analytics - Demographics & Interests for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

We have been using Google Analytics for several years now and recently decided to try collecting the Demographics and Interests information.

I have followed instructions how to enable in analytics web portal and have added the "enableAdvertisingIdCollection" (Android - for example) to the tracker.

It has been over a week and I see NO Demographic or Interests collection data at all.

Does anyone else have this working for Android or iOS (not Website)?